# How do I do decimal arithmetic on two varchars and return result to an aliased column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two fields of type `varchar` that contain numeric values or blank strings, the latter of which I have filtered out to avoid `Divide by Zero` errors.

I am attempting to determine the percentage value that num2 represents in relation to num1, i.e. (Num_2 * 1 / Num_1). Relatively simple math.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to do the math and then cast it to a decimal value. I keep receiving `Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric` errors.

Can someone help me out with the casting issue?

Comment: You can't decide the order that sql will interpret your query. It will most likely filter the rows out first but not always. The biggest issue you are facing is because you are using the wrong datatype. If you want to store numbers you should use any of the numeric datatypes instead of varchar. And in your equation you posted you still need to cast/convert or the logic will be against varchar values which won't work.

Comment: I found a tip on a blog that indicates that arithmetic can be done on varchar without the need for conversion by multiplying by 1. In doing integer math, I can confirm that it works. The issue is that I need a decimal value with 8 decimal places. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2008/01/02/4328.aspx

Comment: Ugh. That is a shortcut for doing some basic math when the datatype is wrong. If you want the result to be in a specific numeric type you will need to cast it. Also, in sql server integer math will result in an integer. In other words 2/3 will result in 0. Cast your varchars to a numeric first and then do your math. Avoid these silly shortcuts in the future and use the proper datatype. You said you want 8 decimal places but how long is the total number? Your query would be something like this (replace the ? with a real value) select cast(Num_2 as decimal(?, 8)) / cast(Num_1 as decimal(?, 8))

Answer (score 1):

You didn't interpret the error correctly.

It is not about casting the result of your math to float, it is about implicit type casting **before** the equation is evaluated.

You have in your table some values that cannot be converted to numeric, because they are not valid numbers or numbers out of range. It is enough that one row contains invalid data to make fail the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you're looking for something similar to this?

```
declare @table table (
  [numerator]     [sysname]
  , [denominator] [sysname]);
insert into @table
        ([numerator],[denominator])
values      (N'1',N'2'),
        (N'9999999999',N'88888888888');
select case
       when isnumeric([numerator]) = 1
            and isnumeric ([denominator]) = 1
           then
         cast([numerator] as [float]) / [denominator]
       else
         null
   end
from   @table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select cast('25.5' as decimal(15, 8)) / cast('100.0' as decimal(15, 8))
```

The example above will return this:

```
0.25500000000000000000000
```

In this case, I'm converting the operand types before they get used in the division.

Remember to replace the literals in my query by your field names.

Answer (score 0):

you said that can be number or blank string. 
son try something like this:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN NUM_2 = '' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(NUM_2 AS NUMERIC(15,4)) END)
    /
    (CASE WHEN NUM_1 = '' THEN 1 ELSE CAST(NUM_1 AS NUMERIC(15,4)) END)
```

you test if string is blank. if it is, you use 0 (or 1, to avoid division by zero)